# Hugo, collapsible code blocks with render hooks possible?

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook, hugo

I would like to create a collapsible code section (for markdown created with jupyter notebooks) similar to what is possible with jupyter-book using cell tags (e.g. "hide-input" https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/interactive/hiding.html)

According to the answer by DevShark in this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71691219/add-collapsible-section-in-hugo), collapsible sections can be inserted via shortcodes like so:

Create a shortcode in `/layouts/shortcodes/details.html`

```
<details>
  <summary>{{ (.Get 0) | markdownify }}</summary>
  {{ .Inner | markdownify }}
</details>
```

This shortcode can be used inside the content file, in markdown, in the following way:

```
{{< details >}}
Collapsed text
{{< /details >}}
```

I was wondering if the same behavior can be achieved using the [render hook for code blocks](https://gohugo.io/templates/render-hooks/).

I tried following snippet in `./layouts/_default/_markup/render-codeblock.html`

```
<details>
    {{ .Inner | markdownify }}
</details>
```

However, the code blocks can be unfolded but the syntax highlighting does not work.

Any ideas how I could obtain foldable code blocks in the html export with syntax highlighting?

Comment: How does the syntax highlighting work? Is this Javascript? My guess is that the JS doesn't apply the highlighting properly. If the section is closed when the page loads, then the JS script may ignore it. So you might need to add some Javascript to apply the highlighting after the user clicks "expand" on the section.

Comment: Hmm, that is a good point. Thank you. Will try with different html elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed modify `render-codeblock.html`. Perform syntax highlighting using Chroma inside Hugo like this:

```
<pre>
    <code>{{ highlight .Inner .Type }}</code>
</pre>
```

You can then add your desired behavior by adding elements/classes to do what you want.
See more: https://gohugo.io/functions/highlight/

Comment: Thank you. I searched the Hugo documentation for hours. No idea why  missed this function.